# Switch cases in a general way

Tags: php

I got a switch with many cases. All of them are working with the same scheme: case -> function with the same name and put the result in the var result.

```
switch ($_POST["field"]) {
    case "keyword1": $result = keyword1(); break;
    case "keyword2": $result = keyword2(); break;
    case "keyword3": $result = keyword3(); break;
}
```

Is it possible to do that with a general code or do I have to do it - like it is shown above - for each case manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the names are exactly like this and also the function names you could do something like this:

```
$result = $_POST["field"]();
```

And to check if the function exists or is callable you can use: [`is_callable()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php) and [`function_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php).

Also so that the user can't call every function you could just create a whitelist where you include the function names which the user can call.

Comment: You mean `if (function_exists(is_callable($_POST['field']))) $antwort = $_POST['field']();`?

Comment: @user3142695 More like: `if(function_exists($_POST['field']) && is_callable($_POST['field']))` Also make sure to check it with a whitelist which functions the user can call!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable function name, but make sure you check the $_POST value's format before you use it, otherwise you're creating a security leak.

```
$functionName = $_POST['field'];

if(!preg_match("/^keyword\d+$/", $functionName) {
    die('Invalid value for POSTDATA entry "field"');
}

$functionName();
```

Answer (score 1):

`call_user_func()` would be much nicer way.
Check it out in manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

But still You HAVE TO filter incoming value or Your code will be VERY insecure... for example You can provide array of allowed functions and check if given `$_POST['field']` value is in that array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) with a whitelist of function names:

```
$funcs = ['func1','funct2'...];
if(in_array($_POST['key'], $funcs)
    $result = call_user_func($_POST['key']);
```

Though i tend to think the switch case is more readable